# Crystal reports if this or that then this2

Tags: crystal-reports, report

So I have text1, text2 and text3. The variable can be text1, text2 or text3. It can also be text1 and text3. But if it is text1 and text3 then I want it to say "text1 and 3".

```
If {Table.column} = 'text1' then "text1" else if
{Table.column} = 'text2' then "text2" else if 
{Table.column} = 'text3' then "text3" else if
{Table.column} = ['text1', 'text3'] then "text1 and 3"
```

I tried this formula with a couple other variations, and it doesnt work. On the front end users screen it produces two records on the report if the variable is text1 and text3. I just want one record saying "text1 and 3".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work like this, if you have possibility of multiple combinations then you should check for the combinations first and then check for individual values else control won't to multiple combinations instead it will get result as soon as single check is true which is what happening in your case, So your logic should be:

```
If {Table.column} IN ['text1', 'text3'] then "text1 and 3"
Else If //All other multiple combinations then individual values
{Table.column} = 'text1' then "text1" 
else if
{Table.column} = 'text2' then "text2" 
else if 
{Table.column} = 'text3' then "text3"
```

Comment: can you post your changed formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
If {Table.column} = ['text1', 'text3'] then "text1 and 3"
{Table.column} = 'text1' then "text1" else if
{Table.column} = 'text2' then "text2" else if 
{Table.column} = 'text3' then "text3"
```

so with this code, if the criteria is text3, then it shows "text1 and 3".

Crystal Reports 2016

Answer (score 0):

also tried

```
If {Table.column} in ['text1', 'text3'] then "text1 and 3" else
{Table.column}
```

along with several other combinations